# get order status from order id, email and customer's last name

Tags: magento-1.8, resource-model, collection-filtering

I'm currently looking for a method from which I can get the order status based on the `order id`, `customer email` and `customer last name`.

I'd written this code so far

```
public function orderHistoryAction(){
    $req = $this->getRequest();
    $oid = $req->getParam('oid', '');
    $lnm = $req->getParam('lnm', '');
    $eml = $req->getParam('eml', '');

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($oid);
    if ($order->getId()) {
        if ((strcasecmp($lnm, $order->getCustomerLastname()) == 0) && (strcasecmp($eml, $order->getCustomerEmail()) == 0)) {
            echo $order->getStatusLabel();
        } else {
            echo 'invalid';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'invalid';
    }
}
```

and is working well for both *customer* and *guest*. But this doesn't seems to me the right approach. I supposed to used something like written in [this blog](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part12-series-collection-sql-operations) or [this blog](http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/collection-and-sql-operations.html). If anybody could make me correct?

Comment: The code looks OK to me.

Comment: @Marius: yes... this code is ok. but is it the right approach? cant I do like as shown in the link?

Comment: The code AND the approach look ok to me. As far as the links you mentioned they are useless in your case. They talk about using collections (lists of objects). You don't have any collections in your code and you don't need them.

Comment: @Marius: you right. but does it can be done in that way. I asked to go through those links for this.

Comment: See my answer in case you want it differently. But I would use your approach also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use collections you can get your order object like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', $oid)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_lastname', $lnm)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $eml);
$order = $collection->getFirstItem();
if ($order->getId()) { 
    echo $order->getStatusLabel();
}
else {
    echo 'invalid';
}
```

But it's kind of the same thing that you did.
I even thing your approach is faster.
In your case you run a select like this.

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order WHERE increment_id = '100000005';
```

In the approach I described you run something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order WHERE increment_id = '100000005' AND customer_lastname='DOE' AND customer_email = 'john.doe@example.com';
```

There is no need for the additional conditions since the `increment_id` must be unique.

Comment: +1 for the answer. `$collection->getFirstItem();` where do it came from? Also, how could i differentiate between `addAttributeToFilter` and `addFieldToFilter`?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal That's a method defined in `Varien_Data_Collection`, the class that is parent to all collections.

Comment: previously I tried that too but the thing I was missing is `$collection->getFirstItem();`.

Comment: So I'm assuming you could make a form and pass the data with GET or POST for the input, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Like Marius said, you don't need a collection for this specific case. If you have to list several order status, then you would use a collection. To make your code more generic (so that you can use it with collections), I would change the interface a little bit:

```
public function getOneOrderHistoryAction() {
    // extract the parameters from $this->request and pass on
    ...
    return $this->getOrderHistory($oid, $nlm, $eml);
}

public function getOrderHistory($oid, $nlm, $eml) {
    // use the arguments provided
    ...
}
```

Also, a small improvement maybe: I think you want [strncasecmp](https://www.php.net/strncasecmp).